# Enable IIS to use remote active directory for windows authentication

Tags: iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have developed a web application in .Net 4 with Windows authentication enabled. I would like to deploy it in a windows server 2008 R2. And I have my Active Directory in another server. How can I authenticate users against the remote Active directory from my application server?
And I need to maintain the authentication mode as Windows authentication

Thanks to all

CMS

Comment: You cannot have your "Active Directory in another server". I guess you installed Active Directory role on another server. That's alright. That server becomes a domain controller of the domain you defined, and you can add the IIS server to that domain so Windows authentication works for that domain.

Answer (score 0):

If the authenticating user already have permission to access the AD, you can simply impersonate as authenticating user:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158